# Консольный запуск программы Linux

Tags: php, алгоритм, веб-программирование, exec

Всем привет!
Есть консольная программа Mystem, пытаюсь её запустить на сервере Linux и обработать данные, но ощущение, что сама программа не запускается, как убедиться, что она запустилась?
Пример кода ниже:

```
$text = "Любимый мой хитер темпераментный кидать книги";
function mystem($q) {   
$result = exec ('echo "'.$q.'" | /mystem/mystem_3_linux_3 -w '); //   
$result =  preg_replace ("/[\?\}\{]/"," ",$result);
return $result;
}

$texts = explode(" ", $text);
foreach ($texts as $answer => $keys) {
echo $answer ."=". mystem($keys);
echo "<br/>";
}
```

Добавлю сервер у меня линуксовый, мне бы определить точно запускается программа и почему она не отдает какие либо данные.

Comment: Сделать вывод. Как запускаете?

Comment: echo "Любимый" | /mystem/mystem_3_linux_3 -i 0=1
    echo "мой" | /mystem/mystem_3_linux_3 -i 1=1
    echo "хитер" | /mystem/mystem_3_linux_3 -i 2=1
    echo "темпераментный" | /mystem/mystem_3_linux_3 -i 3=1
    echo "кидать" | t/mystem/mystem_3_linux_3 -i 5=1
    echo "книги" | /mystem/mystem_3_linux_3 -i 6=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$errorCode = null;
$result = exec ('echo "'.$q.'" | /mystem/mystem_3_linux_3 -w 2>/tmp/out.txt 1>/tmp/out.txt'
    , $errorCode); 
var_dump($errorCode);
```

если консольная команда порождает вывод, то он будет записан в /tmp/out.txt (при наличии прав на запись)
Также, в переменную $errorCode будет записан код возврата. null - не отработало вообще, 0 - все отработало нормально, любое другое значение - ошибка при выполнении.

Comment: Файл оказался просто пустой, может я что-то не так делаю исходя из документации? https://tech.yandex.ru/mystem/doc/index-docpage/

Comment: если файл создался, значит сама команда запускается. что в коде возврата?

Comment: файл не создался, я его создал, после затер, запустил, посмотрел на хостинге, нет данного файла. В выводе на странице отображается array(0) { }

Comment: Если при выполнении exec с добавленными `2>/tmp/out.txt 1>/tmp/out.txt` файл не создался, то есть три варианта 1) у скрипта нет прав на запись в /tmp, тогда поменяйте на папку, куда он точно может писать, 2) mystem_3_linux_3 ничего не возвращает в стандартные потоки, попробуйте запустить команду из шелла и посмотреть вывод, 3) команда не выполняется. Проверьте, есть ли права  у php на запуск этого файла

Comment: Запустил из шела https://yadi.sk/i/mXY2hfLyxxAWy
Segmentation fault
0=<br/>Segmentation fault

Comment: @sanitarn ну вот, все оказалось просто. Разбирайтесь с бинарником, что-то с ним не то.

Comment: Не могу понять, что произошло, но все заработало, советы были по делу, спасибо большое.